# How can I add hyperlinks in a array_ref in Spreadsheet::WriteExcel?

Tags: perl, excel, spreadsheet

I want to write an array reference into Excel like

```
@eec =  ( 
                ['maggie', 'milly', 'molly', 'may'  ], 
                [13,       14,      15,      16     ], 
                ['shell',  'star',  'crab',  'stone'] 
         ); 

$worksheet->write_col('A1', \@eec);
```

But my problem is that I want to **embed hyper-links also**.

I know how to add hyperlink to a particular lable like,

```
$worksheet->write('A4',  'http://www.perl.com/', 'Perl', $format);
```

but  what  should I do to show hyperlink let say on 
label  '`may`'?

for more detail see [Example of how to use the Spreadsheet::WriteExcel module to write 1D and 2D arrays of data](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Examples.pm#Example%3a_write_arrays.pl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The write() method in Spreadsheet::WriteExcel is a [syntactic wrapper](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#write%28%24row,_%24column,_%24token,_%24format%29) for a number of other methods.

In general if it doesn't do what you want there are two remedies: use the wrapped method that you require explicitly or modify the behaviour of the write() method to suit your needs.

If the first case you just need to unroll the implicit loop that write() gives you for nested data. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new( 'example.xls' );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();


my @eec = (
    [ 'maggie', 'milly', 'molly', 'may'   ],
    [ 13,       14,      15,      16      ],
    [ 'shell',  'star',  'crab',  'stone' ]
);


my $row = 0;

for my $aref ( @eec ) {

    my $col = 0;

    for my $token ( @$aref ) {

        if ( $token eq 'may' ) {
            $worksheet->write_url( $row, $col, 'http://foo.com', $token );
        }
        else {
            $worksheet->write( $row, $col, $token );
        }

        $col++;
    }

    $row++;
}

__END__
```

In the second case you can modify write() by using the add_write_handler() method. Have a look at the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm) and [examples](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Examples.pm#Example%3a_write_handler1.pl). This is in the slightly advanced category so if you are new to Spreadsheet::WriteExcel just use the simpler method above.

Comment: P.S. Maggie, Milly, Molly, May. Anyone?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I was also thinking the same solution as given by you in first remedy but I will also try to make a handler for the problem.

Comment: @Nikhil-Jain You need to be careful using add_write_handler() with write_url() since you can end up with infinite recursion. I'll post a small working example later.

Answer (score 0):

AFIU in `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` has no methods for formatting URLs for later writing, so simplest way is add URLs without labels inside arrays as that:

```
@eec =   (
                ['maggie', 'milly', 'molly', 'http://www.perl.com/'  ],
                [13,       14,      15,      16     ],
                ['shell',  'star',  'crab',  'stone'],
            );
```

Or write over specific cell with `$worksheet->write_url` method.